# Create Customizable React Table by filtering Each JSON Object

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, react-table

I'm new to react and I need help as to how I can execute the following.
I want to create a table with 5 columns where each column Header represents the time 1pm,2pm,3pm,4pm,5pm
and 7 rows representing the days from Sunday-Saturday.

The backend will return the following JSON array

**Example:**

```
[{"day": "Sunday", "Time": "2pm", "activity": "Golf"}
{"day": "Sunday", "Time": "3pm", "activity": "Football"}
{"day": "Sunday", "Time": "2pm", "activity": "Basketball"}
{"day": "Monday", "Time": "2pm", "activity": "Sleep"}]
```

I want to check the day and time and write in the corresponding table cell the activity.

**Example:**
The first JSON object, activity "GOLF" should be written in the table cell [Sunday,2pm].
Note: I can have 2 activities map to the same cell

```
-------------------------------------------------------------------
|                 | 1pm     | 2pm          | 3pm           | [...] |
| Sunday          |         | GOLF         | Football      |       |
                              BasketBall
| Monday          |         | Sleep        |               |       |
| Tuesday         |         |              |               |       |
| Wednesday       |         |              |               |       |
| Thursday        |         |              |               |       |
| Friday          |         |              |               |       |
| Saturday        |         |              |               |       |
--------------------------------------------------------------------
```

As I mentioned above, I'm still new to React, so any help directing me to resources that would help me understand Tables in react and how I can implement the above functionalities would be greatly appreciated. I tried reading useTable Hooks but got overwhelmed as to what each of

```
{getTableProps,getTableBodyProps,headerGroups,rows,prepareRow}
```

meant and how I could use them to execute what I want.

What I tried implementing:

```
import React, {useMemo} from 'react'
import {useTable} from 'react-table'
import {COLUMNS} from './Columns'
import MOCK_DATA from './ActivityMOCK.json'
import './table.css'

export const  Table= ()=> {
    const columns = useMemo(()=> COLUMNS, [])
    const data = useMemo(()=> MOCK_DATA,[])
    const tableInstance = useTable({
        columns,
        data

    })
    const {getTableProps,getTableBodyProps,headerGroups,rows,prepareRow} = tableInstance
    return (
        <table {...getTableProps()}>
        <thead>
          {headerGroups.map(headerGroup => (
            <tr {...headerGroup.getHeaderGroupProps()}>
              {headerGroup.headers.map(column => (
                <th {...column.getHeaderProps()}>{column.render('Header')}</th>
              ))}
            </tr>
          ))}
        </thead>
        <tbody {...getTableBodyProps()}>
          {rows.map((row, i) => {
            prepareRow(row)
            return (
              <tr {...row.getRowProps()}>
                {row.cells.map(cell => {
                  return <td {...cell.getCellProps()}>{cell.render('Cell')}</td>
                })}
              </tr>
            )
          })}
        </tbody>
      </table>
    )
}
```

Column.js

```
export const COLUMNS =[
   {
    Header: 'Day',accessor: 'day'
    },
    {
        Header: '1pm', accessor: '1pm'
    },
    {
        Header: '2pm', accessor: '2pm'
    },
    {
        Header: '3pm',accessor: '3pm'
    },
    {
        Header: '4pm',accessor: '4pm'
    },
    {
        Header: '5pm',accessor: '5pm'
    }

]
```

Output:

```
----------------------------------------------------------
|                 | 1pm     | 2pm          | 3pm           | [...] |
| Sunday          |         |              |               |       |
                              
| Sunday          |         |              |               |       |
| Sunday          |         |              |               |       |
| Monday          |         |              |               |       |
--------------------------------------------------------------------
```

I don't want each day to be repeated like that, and I want to add the whole JSON object that maps to the corresponding day/time in the correct cell, but I can't seem to be able to figure out the approach. Should I even useTable?

Comment: So the [quickstart](https://react-table.tanstack.com/docs/quick-start) gave you problems? How far did you get with trying to implement your solution?

Comment: I basically was able to create an empty table with 1pm,2om,3pm.. as headers only. But my actual data isn't being rendered and I don't know how I could set the days of the week as rows

Comment: Well you would have to prepare your data to match, you could see one column as day, and then group all of the incoming data per day / time. You might have a bit more problems when a date is actually introduced at a later time, so you could have a look for that. Some data will be static (based on your example), but the columns seem to be somewhat dynamic, it makes it a bit strange how you would set ranges (time / date from / date to). Feel free to [edit] in your attempt till now, it could be a big help

Comment: The mockdata, is that what you shared as part of your example data? As for columns, you seem to be missing a `Day` accessor as the first column, and your headers for time should point to a property on your rows that matches the data

Comment: Yes, the mockdata is what I shared as my example data. Can you please elaborate more ? I understand that the accessor should point to the JSON attribute I want to display in that specific column, and that setting it to 1pm isn't correct, but I just don't know how to do the following. Displaying a whole JSON object that maps to "time":"1pm" in the first column and a whole JSON object that maps to "day:" "Sunday" in the first row and so on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well first, we need to make sure we get the data correctly in a table format you can use. I think the structure you are showing lacks purpose, having a date would be so much more useful than just a weekday, however I use it here as it is part of your data

```
const dataSet = [{"day": "Sunday", "Time": "2pm", "activity": "Golf"},
{"day": "Sunday", "Time": "3pm", "activity": "Football"},
{"day": "Sunday", "Time": "2pm", "activity": "Basketball"},
{"day": "Monday", "Time": "2pm", "activity": "Sleep"}];

const weekdays = ['Sunday', 'Monday', 'Tuesday', 'Wednesday', 'Thursday', 'Friday', 'Saturday'];

// map all the data you need together
const groupedData = dataSet.reduce( (agg, cur) => {
  // this assumes the day always exists, isn't written differently
  // you may need to proof that a bit better in your real code
  const target = agg[cur.day];
  if (target[cur.Time]) {
    target[cur.Time].push( cur.activity );
  } else {
    target[cur.Time] = [cur.activity];
  }
  return agg;
}, Object.assign( {}, ...weekdays.map( day => ({[day]: {}}) ) ) );

// based on that grouping, extract the keys and make it part of the column data
// time has now become a column, and activity will be an array inside that column
const tableData = Object.keys( groupedData ).map( day => ({ day, ...groupedData[day] }) );
```

This `tableData` you could then use as part of your table instance itself, however, you will probably have to change how the array of activities are rendered.

This does now however mean, that you need to update your columns, something in the line of (I'll try to come with a complete example in a subsequent edit):

```
const CellRenderer = ( { value } ) => {
  if (!value || !Array.isArray( value ) ) {
    return null;
  }
  return (
    <React.Fragment>
      { value.map( v => <div>{ v }</div> ) }
    </React.Fragment>
  );
};
}

export const COLUMNS =[
  {
    accessor: 'day'
  },
  {
    Header: '1pm', accessor: '1pm', Cell: CellRenderer
  },
  {
    Header: '2pm', accessor: '2pm', Cell: CellRenderer
  },
  {
    Header: '3pm',accessor: '3pm', Cell: CellRenderer
  },
  {
    Header: '4pm',accessor: '4pm', Cell: CellRenderer
  },
  {
    Header: '5pm',accessor: '5pm', Cell: CellRenderer
  }
]
```

```js
const { useMemo } = React;
const { useTable } = ReactTable;

window.process = { cwd: () => '' };

// the component, pass columns & data as properties
const Table = ( { columnSet, dataSet } ) => {
    const data = useMemo( () => {
      const weekdays = ['Sunday', 'Monday', 'Tuesday', 'Wednesday', 'Thursday', 'Friday', 'Saturday'];

      // map all the data you need together
      const groupedData = dataSet.reduce( (agg, cur) => {
        // this assumes the day always exists, isn't written differently
        // you may need to proof that a bit better in your real code
        const target = agg[cur.day];
        if (target[cur.Time]) {
          target[cur.Time].push( cur.activity );
        } else {
          target[cur.Time] = [cur.activity];
        }
        return agg;
      }, Object.assign( {}, ...weekdays.map( day => ({[day]: {}}) ) ) );
  
      // based on that grouping, extract the keys and make it part of the column data
      // time has now become a column, and activity will be an array inside that column
      const tableData = Object.keys( groupedData ).map( day => ({ day, ...groupedData[day] }) );
      return tableData;
    }, [ dataSet ] );

    const columns = useMemo( () => columnSet, [columnSet] );

    const tableInstance = useTable({
        columns,
        data
    });
    const {
      getTableProps,
      getTableBodyProps,
      headerGroups,
      rows,
      prepareRow
    } = tableInstance;
    
    return (
        <table {...getTableProps()}>
        <thead>
          {headerGroups.map(headerGroup => (
            <tr {...headerGroup.getHeaderGroupProps()}>
              {headerGroup.headers.map(column => (
                <th {...column.getHeaderProps()}>{column.render('Header')}</th>
              ))}
            </tr>
          ))}
        </thead>
        <tbody {...getTableBodyProps()}>
          {rows.map((row, i) => {
            prepareRow(row)
            return (
              <tr {...row.getRowProps()}>
                {row.cells.map(cell => {
                  return <td {...cell.getCellProps()}>{cell.render('Cell')}</td>
                })}
              </tr>
            )
          })}
        </tbody>
      </table>
    )
}

// the columns and cell rendering
const CellRenderer = ( { value } ) => {
  if (!value || !Array.isArray( value ) ) {
    return null;
  }
  return (
    <React.Fragment>
      { value.map( v => <div key={v}>{ v }</div> ) }
    </React.Fragment>
  );
};


const columns = [
  {
    accessor: 'day'
  },
  {
    Header: '1pm', accessor: '1pm', Cell: CellRenderer
  },
  {
    Header: '2pm', accessor: '2pm', Cell: CellRenderer
  },
  {
    Header: '3pm',accessor: '3pm', Cell: CellRenderer
  },
  {
    Header: '4pm',accessor: '4pm', Cell: CellRenderer
  },
  {
    Header: '5pm',accessor: '5pm', Cell: CellRenderer
  }
]

// the data to be used
const dataSet = [{"day": "Sunday", "Time": "2pm", "activity": "Golf"},
{"day": "Sunday", "Time": "3pm", "activity": "Football"},
{"day": "Sunday", "Time": "2pm", "activity": "Basketball"},
{"day": "Monday", "Time": "2pm", "activity": "Sleep"}];

const target = document.getElementById('container');
ReactDOM.render( <Table 
  columnSet={ columns }
  dataSet={ dataSet } />, target );
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.8.6/umd/react.development.js" integrity="sha512-uDcVu1L9rOVnYAEDiN49qYQuVQeqCNQw7lbiqF8gTNqmFaQw0NFBiFrbGkpbKkIH1HjJpKI7wgvE7tLpSWpMqQ==" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.8.6/umd/react-dom.production.min.js" integrity="sha512-0uQJWYKqppuntnX/9xmazR1YADGh7MAficuBoyioWv37RUVN/ueAeXibDK+acJsa1AjkOtQXc3gO9j/Q3QRxjA==" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/react-table@7.6.2/dist/react-table.development.js"></script>
<div id="container"></div>
```

Comment: what does CellRenderer do?

Comment: @Hoda It should (and I haven't tested it yet), render all activities per time in separate divs

Comment: @Hoda I updated with a working version, I did have to change something to the `CellRenderer`